# Java 8 Filter List of POJO based on a condition

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to extract a sublist where one of the attribute in list of POJO matches with the input at first occurrence.

```
class POJO {
     String name;

     @Nullable
     String location;
}
```

Given a list of POJO, I need to get the List where location matches to input location. Once we find the first occurrence of the location, We need to extract the list from that point to end of list.

```
List<POJO> ans = Lists.newArrayList();
Iterator<POJO> iterator = input
            .iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    POJO pojo = iterator.next();
    if (Objects.nonNull(pojo.location)) {
        String location = pojo.location
        //Got the first location matching with input, From here, Get all the elements from List
        if (inputLocation.equals(location) {
            ans.add(pojo);
            break;
        }
    }
}

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   POJO pojo = iterator.next();
    if (Objects.nonNull(pojo.location)) {
            ans.add(pojo);
       }
}
```

Can anyone suggest any better apporach? (if possible using Streams)?

Comment: `input.stream().filter(item -> inputLocation.equals(item)).findFirst();`

Comment: This gives me the first Element, What about next sublist from that point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Java 9+, you can use dropWhile:

```
List<POJO> ans = input.stream().dropWhile(pojo -> pojo.location == null 
                                           || !inputLocation.equals(pojo.location))
                      .filter(loc -> loc.location != null)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

On Java 8, you'd have to do it in two steps: find the index of your element and then pull the sub-list. This combines the two in one statement:

```
List<POJO> ans = input.subList(IntStream.range(0, input.size())
        .filter(i -> input.get(i).location != null && 
                     input.get(i).location.equals("inputLocation"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(input::size), input.size());
```

Just be aware of `subList`'s behavior. If you want to break the link from `input`, you may want to construct a new list from the result.

Answer (score 0):

In Java9 `dropWhile` was added in streams that will drop elements until the condition is true, and then return the subsequent elements

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-

```
input.stream().dropWhile(item -> ...).collect(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of element using `IntStream` like:

```
int index = IntStream.range(0, answers.size())
        .filter(i -> inputLocation.equals(answers.get(i).getLocation())).findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

Then extract a sub list using above index like below if index is greater than `-1` :

```
answers.subList(index, answers.size())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `filter` and `dropWhile` operations:

```
List<Pojo> list = List.of(new Pojo("a","USA"),new Pojo("b","UK"),
                        new Pojo("c","USA"), new Pojo("d","UK"));
List<Pojo> remaining = list.stream()
            .filter(p->p.location()!=null)
            .dropWhile(p1->!p1.location().equals("UK"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(remaining);
```

Output:

```
[Pojo[name=b, location=UK], Pojo[name=c, location=USA], Pojo[name=d, location=UK]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant solution compared to the rest of the answer but just a different flavor
Picked input data from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67069275/2987755)
Logic is once we encounter the first matching condition, set the flag, and use it in the stream filter stage.
Since we need variable to be effective final in lambda,  `final Boolean[] isFirstEncounter = {false};` one of the bad workaround.
Also following code should be use in sequential stream and not in parallel stream.

```java
final Boolean[] isFirstEncounter = {false};
List<POJO> input = List.of(new POJO("a", "USA"), new POJO("b", "UK"), new POJO("c", "USA"), new POJO("d", "UK"));
List<POJO> ans = input.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(p -> {
                    if (!isFirstEncounter[0] && "UK".equals(p.location) {
                        isFirstEncounter[0] = true; // true means accept all the elements 
                    }
                    return isFirstEncounter[0]; // false means filter all the elements
                }
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(ans);

//output
// [Solution.POJO(name=b, location=UK), Solution.POJO(name=c, location=USA), Solution.POJO(name=d, location=UK)]
```